# How to define a Variadic template class's method in cpp file?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I am trying to create a variadic class `A` and place the definition of its constructor in the cpp file. I tried `A::A(Args.. args)` and `A<Args...>::A(Args.. args)` both of them did not worked.

How to define a variadic template class in cpp file in c++11?

// A.h

```
#include <tuple>

template<typename... Args>
struct A
{
    std::tuple<Args...> args_;

    A(Args... args);
    void print();
};
```

//A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"


template<typename... Args>
A::A(Args.. args){
  args_ = std::make_tuple(args...);
}

template<typename... Args>
void A::print(){
   // code to print 
}
```

// main.cpp

```
#include "A.cpp"

int main()
{
    A<int, int, int> a = A<int, int, int>(1, 2, 3);
}
```

Comment: How did you conclude that **none of them worked**?

Comment: that might be over statement I will edit the question

Comment: `A<Args...>::A(Args... args)` with **twice** three points `...`.

Comment: And `void A<Args...>::print()`

Comment: @O'Neil Thank you .. I was missing one extra dot `A::A(Args.. args){` .. so `A<Args...>::A(Args... args){` did it .. thank you

Comment: *"`#include "A.cpp"`"*. cpp files should not be included. Rename the file `A.inl` or `A.hxx`...